# is it possible to lock Sim Card Using Gammu

Tags: gammu

Please help, i need information how to lock my SIM card.
For security purpose i want to lock using new PIN Code. 
I operate sim card using modem and access it with gammuservice. Is It possible lock simcard using gammu. if it is not, any bode can explain the alternative. I need lock it programmaticly

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know PUK code, it should be possible using:

```
gammu entersecuritycode PUK currentpuk newpin
```

See documentation for more details: https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/index.html#cmdoption-gammu-arg-entersecuritycode

Comment: hi big thanks, but i still wonder can break my sim card using command from gammu.???

Comment: No, it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: please help need advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097689/enable-sim-lock-using-at-command-vb-net